# how to create webview override method

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, overriding

I am having

```
   1.webview
      a.webview.xib
      b.webview.h
      c.webview.m
   2.webview1
      a.webview1.xib
      b.webview1.h
      c.webview1.m files
```

i want to create override method for webview.m from webview1.m file.
whatever the contents i have loaded in webview1 it should to load in webview...

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webview should be a subclass of WebView1

Comment: Are you new to iOS or new to OOP ?